# How to change color of part of text that is in the same Div with D3/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a tooltip that has multiple different divs inside it. Each row is basically a div. The picture below is what I am aiming to achieve. The problem that i have encountered is that the 13 / 100 is one div, so i cant make the '39' red and the '/ 100' grey. It all has to be red or grey. Is there a way for me to do that inline? something like  tooltip.selectAll(".tooltipScore").text(score(change color here) + " / 100")? I thought of one way where i create another div below the score, and using positioning move it left and up from its position, but i am trying to avoid that and it seems a little hacky.

[image: What the tooltip is supposed to look like]

```
import React, {Component, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import ExperienceScoresData from './experience_scores';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { select, csv, selectAll} from 'd3';
import { extent, max, min } from "d3-array";

class Linechart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.createBarChart = this.createBarChart.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createBarChart()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.createBarChart()
  }

  createBarChart() {
    var margin = {top: 85, right: 60, bottom: 60, left: 80},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var node = this.node
    var divObj = select(node)
    var svgObj = divObj
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    //Read the data
    d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/QamarFarooq/data-for-testing/main/5_OneCatSevNumOrdered.csv", function(data) {

      // group the data: I want to draw one line per group
      var sumstat = d3.nest() // nest function allows to group the calculation per level of a factor
        .key(function(d) { return d.name;})
        .entries(data);
      //console.log(sumstat)



      // Define the div for the tooltip
      var tooltip = divObj
        .append("div")  
        .attr("class","tooltip")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .style("background-color", "white")
        .style("box-shadow","0 0 4px #000000")
        .style("padding", "10px")

      const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

      var d = new Date();

      tooltip.append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltipDate")
      .html(monthNames[d.getMonth()] + " " + "(" + d.getFullYear() + ")")
      .style("font-size", "20px")
      .style("text-align","center")
        
      tooltip.append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltipName")
      .style("text-align","center")
      .style("color","grey")

      tooltip.append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltipTitle")
      .style("text-align","center")
      .html("Customer Sentiment")
      .style("padding-top","10px")

      tooltip.append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltipScore")
      .style("text-align","center")
      .style("color",'DarkGrey')
      .style("font-size", "20px")

      tooltip.append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltipPerception")
      .style("text-align","center")


   
      // Add title for linechart
      svgObj.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", 25)
        .attr("x", 110)
        .attr("y", -50)
        .text("Online Ratings");      

      // Add X axis --> it is a date format
      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }))
        .range([ 0, width ]);
      svgObj.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .attr("stroke-width","0.3")
        .style("opacity","0.5")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(-height).tickFormat('').ticks(5))
      
      // ticks
      svgObj.append("g")
      .style("opacity","0.7")
        .style("font", "14px times")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));
        
      // Add Y axis  
      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.n; })])
        .range([ height, 0 ]);
      svgObj.append("g")
        .attr("stroke-width","0.3")
        .style("opacity","0.5")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(-width).tickFormat('').ticks(5))
        
      // ticks
      svgObj.append("g")
      .style("opacity","0.7")
        .style("font", "14px times")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));

      // Add X axis label:
      svgObj.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", 20)
        .attr("x", width/2 + margin.left)
        .attr("y", height + 50)
        .style("fill", d3.color("grey"))
        .text("Year Of Birth");

      // Add Y axis label:
      svgObj.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", 20)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("x", -height/2 + 40)
        .attr("y", -margin.left + 25)
        .style("fill", d3.color("grey"))
        .text("N-Value")
        
      // color palette
      var key = sumstat.map(function(d){ return d.key }) // list of group names

      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(key)
        .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a'])

      // Add one DOT in the legend for each name.
      svgObj.selectAll(".dots")
        .data(key)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return 250 + i*120})
          .attr("cy", -30) 
          .attr("r", 7)
          .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d)})

      // Add LABEL for legends of each dot.
      svgObj.selectAll(".labels")
        .data(key)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
          .style("fill", d3.color("grey"))
          .attr("x", function(d,i){ return 270 + i*120})
          .attr("y", -28) 
          .text(function(d){ return d})
          .attr("text-anchor", "left")
          .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")

      // Highlight individual line and show tooltip
      var highlightAndShowTooltip = function(d) {
          
          //show tooltip
          tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");

          var selected_line = d.key
          
          // first every group turns grey
          svgObj.selectAll(".line")
            .transition().duration(200)
            .style("opacity", "0.5")

          svgObj.selectAll(".dot")
            .transition().duration(200)
            .style("opacity", "0.5")
          
          // Second the hovered line takes its color
          svgObj.selectAll("." + selected_line)
            .transition().duration(200)
            .style("stroke", color(selected_line))
            .style("opacity", "1")
          
          svgObj.selectAll("." + selected_line)
            .transition().duration(200)
            .style("stroke", color(selected_line))
            .style("opacity", "1")

          //Data for Tooltip
          tooltip.selectAll(".tooltipName")
                .html(d.key)

          var score = 12 //this will be dynamic, for now i just set it to 12 to test it out
          
          tooltip.selectAll(".tooltipScore")
                .text(score + " / 100")
      }

      // UnHighlight and hide tooltip
      var doNotHighlightAndHideTooltip = function(d) {
        
        //hide tooltip
        tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden")

        //return other lines back to normal opacity
        svgObj.selectAll(".line")
            .transition().duration(200).delay(50)
            .style("stroke", function(d){ return( color(d.key))})
            .style("opacity", "1")
        
        svgObj.selectAll(".dot")
            .transition().duration(200).delay(50)
            .style("stroke", function(d){ return( color(d.name))})
            .style("opacity", "1")
      }

      // keep showing tooltip as cursor moves along line
      var keepShowingTooltip = function(d) {
          tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px")
      }

      // Draw the line
      svgObj.selectAll(".line")
          .data(sumstat)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
            .attr("class", function (d) { return "line " + d.key} ) // 2 class for each line: 'line' and the group name
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
            .attr("stroke-width", 4.5)
            .attr("d", function(d){
              return d3.line()
                .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(+d.n); })
                (d.values)
            })
            .on("mouseover", highlightAndShowTooltip)
            .on("mousemove", keepShowingTooltip)
            .on("mouseout", doNotHighlightAndHideTooltip )

      // Draw dots on points
      svgObj.selectAll(".dot")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
              .attr("class", function (d) { return "dot " + d.name } ) // 2 class for each line: 'line' and the group name
              .style("fill","white")
              .style("stroke-width", "3px")
              .style("stroke", function (d) { return color(d.name) })
              .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.year); })
              .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.n); })
              .attr("r", 5.5)
    })

    }
    render() {
      return <div ref={node => this.node = node} className="example_div"> </div>
   }
}

export default Linechart;
```

Comment: Where does the content come from?

Comment: it is a nested array that i created using d3 that is binded. so it would be d.score

Comment: Perhaps you should add some data to your question and create a working example?

Comment: I didnt want to copy paste the whole thing because it is alot of code, i only posted the relevent content, but ok, i will post the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.tooltipScore` is a div, you can change this `.text(score + " / 100")` to use `.html()` instead. Then, you can use a `span` to colour the text differently:

```js
var score = 12;

d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltipScore")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .style("color", 'DarkGrey')
  .style("font-size", "20px")
  .html("<span style='color: #cb9f9e;'>" + score + "</span> / 100")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it worked! i had no idea you could do that. Thanx a bunch!